# Deploy a Gulp build after Git push

Tags: git, deployment, gulp

I just finished a **Gulp** script to optimize my Wordpress projects. Here is my theme structure :

---

**ROOT**

- /**dev**/ (files for work)
- /**bower.json**  (bower packages list)
- /**gulpfile.js** (all my gulp tasks like minify, concat, ...)
- /**package.json** (node packages list)
- /**node_modules**/ (gulp packages)
- /**bower_components**/ (front packages used in my theme)

---

My `gulp build` command create a /**dist**/ directory containing the "*ready to go*" theme.

I'm only tracking the /dev/ directory and gulpfile.js, package.json files with GitLab. My goal is the following :

> For each `push origin master`, I want to deploy the "/dist/" directory on my
>   production server in "/wp-content/themes/theme-name/".

**Any idea ? I'm struggling with this :(**

Answer (score 0):

A [git hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) is probably what you want

> The pre-push hook runs during git push, after the remote refs have been updated but before any objects have been transferred. It receives the name and location of the remote as parameters, and a list of to-be-updated refs through stdin. You can use it to validate a set of ref updates before a push occurs (a non-zero exit code will abort the push).

So all you have to do is creating a git hook that triggers the push to your remote server in the form of a bash command

Comment: I'm already using git hooks, but it was only to "copy/paste" my git repo into the server. I don't see how I can achieve my goal ?

Comment: Or maybe by building, deleting other files, etc ... by CLI ?

Comment: Add a pre-push hook on your development environment which uploads your dist folder to the designated folder on your server

Answer (score 0):

We can't mess around and test without access to your server, so all I can say is "I'd try…" but if you have FTP set up I'd try [`vinyl-ftp`](https://github.com/morris/vinyl-ftp).

This example is lifted straight from the `vinyl-ftp` (0.5.0, 2016-06-18) documentation, just to make this answer a little more comprehensive. You'll need to customize the `globs` and `base` variables and the `conn` targets. (You might also drop the `log` parameter)

```
var gutil = require( 'gulp-util' );
var ftp = require( 'vinyl-ftp' );

gulp.task( 'deploy', function () {

    var conn = ftp.create( {
        host:     'mywebsite.tld',
        user:     'me',
        password: 'mypass',
        parallel: 10,
        log:      gutil.log
    } );

    var globs = [
        'src/**',
        'css/**',
        'js/**',
        'fonts/**',
        'index.html'
    ];

    // using base = '.' will transfer everything to /public_html correctly
    // turn off buffering in gulp.src for best performance

    return gulp.src( globs, { base: '.', buffer: false } )
        .pipe( conn.newer( '/public_html' ) ) // only upload newer files
        .pipe( conn.dest( '/public_html' ) );

} );
```